# Alineación de icono dentro de Input Text

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estoy tratando de hacer un input con un icono dentro. Pero el icono debe estar del lado derecho, no puedo lograr que se cambie de lugar.
La propiedad float no está resultando.
¿Alguien sabe cómo podría lograrlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <style> 
         .input-icons img { 
            position: absolute;
            padding:2px;
         } 
         .input-icons { 
            width: 100%; 
            margin-bottom: 10px; 
         } 
         .icon {
            min-width: 30px;
         } 
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="input-icons"> 
         <img width="25px" height="18px" class="icon" onclick="alert('Hola')" src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/991/298/png-transparent-computer-icons-eye-icon-eye-side-miscellaneous-text-logo.png">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Username"> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Es un simple ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si queres usar `position: absolute` tal vez esto pueda ayudarte.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
.input-icons {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.input-icons img {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px;
  right: -5px;
  min-width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-icons input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px 0px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-icons">
<div class="container">
  <img width="25px" height="18px" class="icon" onclick="alert('Hola')" src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/991/298/png-transparent-computer-icons-eye-icon-eye-side-miscellaneous-text-logo.png">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Acá hay algunos ejemplos y [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) (en ingles)

Answer (score 1):

La instruccion float: right; y text-align-right no funcionan con objetos con posicion absolute, para alinear a la derecha puedes usar la instruccion right o bien la instruccion margin-left ejemplo

```
.input-icons img { right: 85%; }

.input-icons img { margin-left: 143px; }
```

Puede que tengas que usar z-index en caso de que no puedar dar click en el input, la cantidad de margin a la derecha tendras que sacarla basandote en tus dimensiones, trata de usar porcentajes para que sea mas exacto y no afecte el resposive